# How do I add a node after a certain node while inserting it into an existing xml document?

Tags: xml, vb.net

I can't seem to add a node after after another node using the XmlDocument approach. I've tried the methods of the `XMLdocument` but they don't seem to give
me what I need.

The existing xml file that looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <FileZillaServer>
 <Groups/>
 <Users>
    <User Name="dbrown">
       <Option Name="Pass">2ac9cb7dc02b3c0083eb70898e549b63</Option>
       <IpFilter>
           <Disallowed/>
           <Allowed/>
      </IpFilter>
      <Permissions>
          <Permission Dir="C:\inetpub\wwwroot">
              <Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
          </Permission>
      </Permissions>
      <SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">
          <Download/>
          <Upload/>
      </SpeedLimits>
    </User>
 </Users>
 <User Name="3">
    <Option Name="Pass"/>
    <IPFilter>
        <Disallowed/>
        <Allowed/>
    </IPFilter>
    <Permissions>
       <Permission Dir="C:\inetpub\wwwroot">
            <Option Name="FileRead"/>
       </Permission>
    </Permissions>
    <SpeedLimits DType="0" DLimit="10" ServerDLimitBypass="0" UType="0" ULimit="10" ServerULimitBypass="0">
         <Download/>
         <Upload/>
    </SpeedLimits>
    <PrivateFtpAccountId-3>55555</PrivateFtpAccountId-3>
    <PrivatePassword-3>test5</PrivatePassword-3>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-3>66666</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
    <PublicPassword-3>test6</PublicPassword-3>
  </User>
  </FileZillaServer>
```

I ran my console app code code to add this new node section below, however I want to add it just after the first User group  ----> ....

```
  <User Name="3">
    <Option Name="Pass"/>
    <IPFilter>
        <Disallowed/>
        <Allowed/>
    </IPFilter>
    <Permissions>
        <Permission Dir="C:\inetpub\wwwroot">
            <Option Name="FileRead"/>
        </Permission>
    </Permissions>
    <SpeedLimits DType="0" DLimit="10" ServerDLimitBypass="0" UType="0" ULimit="10" ServerULimitBypass="0">
         <Download/>
         <Upload/>
    </SpeedLimits>
    <PrivateFtpAccountId-3>55555</PrivateFtpAccountId-3>
    <PrivatePassword-3>test5</PrivatePassword-3>
    <PublicFtpAccountId-3>66666</PublicFtpAccountId-3>
    <PublicPassword-3>test6</PublicPassword-3>
  </User>
```

Can't seem to get it to work.

My console app code is:

```
    Dim xmleUserNameRoot As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement10 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement20 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement21 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement22 As XmlElement
    Dim xmleOptionElement23 As XmlElement

    Dim xmleIpFilterRoot As XmlElement
    Dim xmlePermissionsGroup As XmlElement
    Dim xmlePermissionRoot As XmlElement
    Dim xmleSpeedLimits As XmlElement

    Dim xmleElementPrivateFtpAcctId As XmlElement
    Dim xmleElementPrivatePassword As XmlElement
    Dim xmleElementPublicFtpAcctId As XmlElement
    Dim xmleElementPublicPassword As XmlElement

    Dim count As Integer
    Dim strId As String
    Dim strPrivateFtpAcctId As String
    Dim strPrivatePassword As String
    Dim strPublicFtpAcctId As String
    Dim strPublicPassword As String

    strPrivateFtpAcctId = "55555"
    strPrivatePassword = "test5"
    strPublicFtpAcctId = "66666"
    strPublicPassword = "test6"

    ' Can be any Id.
    strId = "3"

    ' Create a new XmlDocument class, and use the Load method to load the XML file.
    Dim myXmlDocument As New XmlDocument()

    ' The XmlDocument class represents the XML document and has a Load method to load the document from a file, stream, or an XmlReader.
    ' So load in the XML file.
    myXmlDocument.Load("MyFiLeZillaforadding.xml")

    ' For starting User Name.
    xmleUserNameRoot = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("User")

    ' Create an attribute and set its value to that of the new id.
    xmleUserNameRoot.SetAttribute("Name", strId)
    myXmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmleUserNameRoot)

    ' Create a new element with an attribute and add it in to the User group.
    xmleOptionElement1 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement1.SetAttribute("Name", "Pass")
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement1)

    ' Create the new "IPFilter" root.
    xmleIpFilterRoot = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("IPFilter")

    ' Add elements to the "IPFilter" root.
    xmleOptionElement20 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Disallowed")
    xmleIpFilterRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement20)

    xmleOptionElement21 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Allowed")
    xmleIpFilterRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement21)

    ' Add the "IPFilter" root.
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleIpFilterRoot)

    ' Create the new "Permissions" group.
    xmlePermissionsGroup = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Permissions")

    ' Create the new "Permission" root.
    xmlePermissionRoot = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Permission")
    xmlePermissionRoot.SetAttribute("Dir", "C:\inetpub\wwwroot")

    ' Add elements to the "Permission" root.
    xmleOptionElement10 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Option")
    xmleOptionElement10.SetAttribute("Name", "FileRead")
    xmlePermissionRoot.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement10)

     ' Add the "Permission" root to the "Permissions" group.
    xmlePermissionsGroup.AppendChild(xmlePermissionRoot)

    ' Add the "Permissions" group.
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmlePermissionsGroup)

    ' Create the new "SpeedLimits" root.
    xmleSpeedLimits = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("SpeedLimits")

    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("ServerULimitBypass", "0")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("ULimit", "10")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("UType", "0")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("ServerDLimitBypass", "0")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("DLimit", "10")
    xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("DType", "0")

    ' Add elements to the "SpeedLimits" root.
    xmleOptionElement22 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Download")
    xmleSpeedLimits.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement22)

    xmleOptionElement23 = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("Upload")
    xmleSpeedLimits.AppendChild(xmleOptionElement23)

    ' Add the "SpeedLimits" root.
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleSpeedLimits)

    ' Add the remaining to User Name="#".
    xmleElementPrivateFtpAcctId = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PrivateFtpAccountId-" & strId)
    xmleElementPrivateFtpAcctId.InnerText = strPrivateFtpAcctId
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleElementPrivateFtpAcctId)

    xmleElementPrivatePassword = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PrivatePassword-" & strId)
    xmleElementPrivatePassword.InnerText = strPrivatePassword
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleElementPrivatePassword)

    xmleElementPublicFtpAcctId = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PublicFtpAccountId-" & strId)
    xmleElementPublicFtpAcctId.InnerText = strPublicFtpAcctId
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleElementPublicFtpAcctId)

    xmleElementPublicPassword = myXmlDocument.CreateElement("PublicPassword-" & strId)
    xmleElementPublicPassword.InnerText = strPublicPassword
    xmleUserNameRoot.AppendChild(xmleElementPublicPassword)

    ' Get the first User.
    ' ----> Can't see to get the first user. I tried a number of the XmlDocument methods with no sucess.


    ' Add the whole User Name="#" group after this first User.


    ' Save in place.
    myXmlDocument.Save("MyFiLeZillaforadding.xml")

    Console.WriteLine("The XML file was saved successfully.")
```

Regards...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're creating the 'User' Node of the new data you are wanting to add to the document, and then just appending it to the end of the document here:

```
xmleUserNameRoot.SetAttribute("Name", strId)
myXmlDocument.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmleUserNameRoot)
```

What you need to do is find the `Users` Node in the existing document, and then add your new `User` node to that.

For that you'll get the child nodes and then find the one that is `Users`, and `.appendChild` to that.

The [documentation on the XmlDocumentClass](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) should help.

**EDIT**

So knowing the structure of your xml file, and that the `Users` Node was a child node of the last child node of the document, I was able to access that node with this code:

```
    Dim docNodes As XmlNodeList = myXmlDocument.LastChild.ChildNodes()

    For Each node As XmlNode In docNodes
        If node.Name = "Users" Then
            node.AppendChild(xmleUserNameRoot)
        End If
    Next
```

Alternatively, Since knowing that the `Users` Node is the last node of the `FileZillaServer` Node, which is in turn the last node of the document, you could simply do

```
myXmlDocument.LastChild.LastChild.AppendChild(xmleUserNameRoot)
```

That's not very flexible, but it works!

Comment: ' Get the first User.
' ----> Can't see to get the first user. I tried a number of the XmlDocument methods with no success.


' Add the whole User Name="#" group after this first User.

Comment: Hit the enter key to soon..haha. Anyway..yes that AppendChild code does not belong there. It belongs at the bottom once I find the User node. Problem I am having is that I tried most of the methods to find the User childnode but with no success. Was not sure what I was doing wrong...and I basically deleted those method call attempt for sake of discussion.

Comment: You shouldn't need to find the user child node, if I understand correctly what you're trying to do.  All you need is to find it's `Users` Parent Node and append your new node onto the end of that, in which case it will be added under along side the first existing User Node.

Comment: I opted for the first solution as I had actually left a number of nodes out of the example xml files as to keep the file small in size for discussion. So the 2nd solution would not prevail given Users would not be the last node....Thanks so much.    Any chance you know how to handle attributes? I'm trying to add in an attribute that has a pipe character |. For example:         'xmleSpeedLimits.SetAttribute("ServerU|LimitBypass", "0")   It won't allow it. I tried to escape it with no success.

Answer (score 0):

This line will select the first User element within myXmlDocument to xmlNodeFirstUser

```
Dim xmlNodeFirstUser As XmlNode = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//User")
```

Define the node you want to insert here

```
Dim xmlNodeToInsert As XmlNode
```

This should insert the Node you want to insert after the first User Element within the xml doc

```
myXmlDocument.InsertAfter(xmlNodeToInsert, xmlNodeFirstUser)
```

Using a combination of `XmlDocument` methods within .Net, the `SelectSingleNode(string xpathExpression)` and `InsertAfter(XmlNode toInsert, XmlNode insertAfterMe)`, you should be able to manipulate and traverse around an Xml Document with ease: [Please look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx)
You should also look into XPath Expressions in order to select which nodes you want.

Comment: I tried as you suggested but I get: Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The reference node is not a child
 of this node. I added: Dim xmlNodeFirstUser As XmlNode = myXmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//User") and tha returns the User node. I hten added:        myXmlDocument.InsertAfter(xmleUserNameRoot, xmlNodeFirstUser)   the first arguementis defeind as XmlElement as that is what I am using. I think that is why it is failing.

Comment: Try using `myXmlDocument.DocumentElement.InsertAfter()` in addition to trying to use an XmlNode instead of an XmlElement.

Edit - Normally the error The reference node is not a child of this node is saying xmlNoeFirstUser is not a child node of myXmlDocument.